Avoid some strange ^G on a g/^/norm pattern
I'm working on a 2 pass way to modify only lines that match with a set of matchs: c then a
My input data does not have ^G:
$ cat -A tlines.txt 
Bonjour les amis comment allez-vous ?$
Ha ha ha cintia je vous ai bien eu !$
Hello friends, how are you $
$

How to get rid of the leading ^G I got after a first match ?
$ ex -s '+g/^/norm! 0i"^[fcfaiXX^[A"' +%p +q! tlines.txt 2>/dev/null | cat -A
"Bonjour les amis comment XXallez-vous ?"$
^G"Ha ha ha cintiXXa je vous ai bien eu !"$
"Hello friends, how are you $
"$
$ 

Using the vim --not-a-term does not help
$ vim --not-a-term -e -s '+g/^/norm! 0i"^[fcfaiXX^[A"' +%p +q! tlines.txt 2>/dev/null | cat -A
"Bonjour les amis comment XXallez-vous ?"$
^G"Ha ha ha cintiXXa je vous ai bien eu !"$
"Hello friends, how are you $
"$
$


I have a suspicion there’s an error that occurs (C-g is a BEL character), so Vim rang the terminal bell?
